# What is the best practice for updating database objects in Java Spring Hibernate project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I would like to update a field by a unique ID in a MySQL database.

First method: fetch the object (`select * from`) from the database using unique ID (by `uniqueresult()`), then set the desired value to object and `saveOrUpdate` is performed.

Second method is to write an update query in a DAO implementation (`update table tab set tab.name=123 where...`, `executeUpdate()`), also the same result.

Which is a good way to perform update operation and why?

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are using `Hibernate`, why would you do it in native `SQL` when you can just use **[`Hibernate` Sessions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html)**'s  `.get()`, `.load()`, `.merge()` `.update()` methods.

Here's an example from Hibernate documentation to modify a persistent object:

```
DomesticCat cat = (DomesticCat) sess.load( Cat.class, new Long(69) );
cat.setName("PK");
sess.flush();  // changes to cat are automatically detected and persisted
```

For further reading you can check [**Modifying persistent objects**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-modifying) and [**Modifying detached objects**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-detached) sections in Hibernate documentation.

And according to the documentation :

> The most straightforward way to update the state of an object is to `load()` it and then manipulate it directly while the Session is open.

I hope this answers both your questions *Which is a good way to perform update operation and why?*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "good way" to perform the update you want to. It entierly depend on your needs.

Both method work, but the first will permit you to update more than one field without having to modify your sql query. It will be the responsability of the developper to take care at the state of the object before calling the saveOrUpdate method.

The second method will ensure that no other field will be update in database.

Answer you on your future needs. Do you only need this field to be updated? Can it change in the future? What will be the inpact of both method on the application?

Then you will have your answer.